# BigQuery setup from Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I would like some guidance to setup BigQuery data storage from Google Analytics.

We have 6 different websites which 4 of them belongs to a project and 2 of them to another, but we would like to analyse the data both separately for each site; the projects separately with the sites data; and all the sites together.

Hence, which is the best structure to setup in BigQuery?:
Two projects, with 4 and 2 datasets, or 1 main project with 2 datasets and 4 and 2 tables? or is that even possible.

Or is it so easy to extract the data that it doesn't matter, we can just put every site in an own project and extract the data as we want them.

Please give me some guidance in this issue

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:

> Or is it so easy to extract the data that it doesn't matter, we can just put every site in an own project and extract the data as we want them.

Yes!

The longer answer:

You can extract data from only one view per property ([Set up a BigQuery Export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092)), so start by identifying which one you'll link and ensure the settings are the same across all of the views you are going to import, assuming this is important to you.

Each profile/site will go into it's own dataset and will be partitioned by day, making it easy to query them individually, or together, as required.

**It is possible to query across projects, so if you store data across two, you'll still be able to join them.**

In my opinion it would make things easier for analysts if the data was all in one project, as you'll be able to save queries in a single location and track the query costs centrally, but if you need to keep 2 projects your data can still be connected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @FredrikGunnarsson No problem! If you feel my response answered your question please consider accepting it as a solution. Best of luck with your BigQuery adventures!